# How to play a sound in Silverlight without XAML

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mediaelement

Looks like `MediaElement` requires XAML to work.

So this simple code doesn't work :

```
MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
me.Volume = 1;
me.AutoPlay = false;
me.Source = new Uri("http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3");
me.Play();
```

Is there another way to play sound in Silverlight 4 with MVVM - or do I have to find a placeholder for the media element in my XAML ?

This thread describes how to use XNA for Win Phone 7 - but I'm talking regular Silverlight
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/60e7e4b4-31dc-4a81-bdfb-e2c80e761a1c

Comment: Did you ever find a way to use a MediaElement without XAML?  More specifically, I need a way to play sound from a non-UI thread in Silverlight.  Ideas?

Comment: sorry I didn't. I had to concede and use a placeholder in the XAML

Answer (score 0):

The control still needs to be in the visual tree to operate.  If you don't want it to actually appear, you could have it collapsed.  But you'll need to do something like:

```
me.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(me);
```